# How much time passed between The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe and Prince Caspian?

Tags: time-travel, time, the-chronicles-of-narnia

The book series will nonchalantly say "hundreds" or "a thousand" or "thousands" of years in different places throughout, but is it ever stated exactly how much time passed between Peter, Susan, Edmund, and Lucy's first departure from Narnia and their first entrance back into it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In this [Timeline](http://narnia.wikia.com/wiki/Narnian_timeline) which is generally believed to be accurate as some if not all are based on actual notes by CS Lewis. We see its been almost **1300 years** since the Lion, the Witch, and The Wardrobe.

[image: Timeline of significant events in Narnia]

Comment: Uggghhhh, another Wikia-based answer. BRB, finding a proper source ...

Answer (score 11):

Between their departure from Narnia and their return, 1288 Narnian years passed (in one Earth year):

> The events of The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe occured [sic] between 1000 and 1015 NY [Narnian Year], and in 1940 AD on Earth.

([*The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe (book)* on WikiNarnia](http://narnia.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lion,_the_Witch,_and_the_Wardrobe_(book)))

> Due to the anomalies found between Earth time and Narnian, this story takes place in Narnian-year 2303 and Earth year 1941.

([*Prince Caspian (book)* on WikiNarnia](http://narnia.wikia.com/wiki/Prince_Caspian_(book)))

Comment: So then how much time between Caspian and The Dawn Treader?

Comment: @MyCodeSucks ask another question on the site.